# Calling servlet to load the data using jquery ajax?

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, html

I am new to JQuery. I have a servlet which will fetch data from the database and the result is kept is request and the same result is retrieved in jsp file. Now i have to call the servlet using ajax jquery to load the data. I am doing as below. But it is not loading. Please help me.

```
$('#myForm #revert').click(function() {

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "./myController",
            success: function(msg) {
                <span style="color:green;font-weight:bold">Successful</span>');
            },
            error: function(ob,errStr) {
                //Todo

            }
        });

        });
```

Servlet code:

```
//Service call gets data and the result is kept in request scope as below
request.setAttribute("myresult", result);
request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/myScreen.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

Thanks!

Comment: I doubt this is valid JS - have you checked in your browsers error console?

Answer (score 1):

Ajax is not a normal `HTTPRequest`,You canot Forward or `sendRedirect` a Ajax request

Since it is Asynchronous,you need to write the  response for Ajax request

```
PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
out.println(resultString);
return;
```

Please read @Balusc great answer :[How to use Servlets and Ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112686/how-to-use-servlets-and-ajax)

Comment: suresh, Thanx for ur reply. How can the data is forwarded to jsp? do i need do any changes in jquery? Thanks

Comment: @user1016403 A complete example ..from `HTML` to `Response writing` is given there.If you still have a doubt,Please let me know.

Comment: it just says how display small text.But here i get list of objects from database which needs to be displayed in jsp table. Please help me...

Comment: @user1016403 send that list as a Json string to client.That is the only way I know.

Comment: @user1016403  This is the [best link](http://www.programming-free.com/2012/09/ajax-with-servlets-using-jquery-and-json.html#.UgIjA5IepGQ) I can provide for you ,so far.